# How do we ensure that during reentry or descent of spent stages, it doesnt hit any aircraft or incoming rocket?

Tags: spacecraft, reentry, debris, removedebris-mission

When a rocket is launched, stages are separated at different intervals and altitude. The lower stages usually descend immediately while upper stages and orbital platforms usually last in space a bit longer. Are these also tracked like satellites and does a warning system exists for aircrafts and rockets?

Comment: I would assume NOTAM is in place for air traffic on expected trajectory. https://pbs.twimg.com/media/E5xuLI7WEAMknLG?format=jpg&name=4096x4096

Comment: @BojanKogoj: Nitpick: A NOTAM (NOTice to Air Missions) is just a notification that is sent out by the FAA. It is basically a newsletter. A NOTAM can contain any sort of information. For example, the FAA sends out NOTAMS that contain corrections and updates to charts and maps. What you mean is a *Temporary Flight Restriction (TFR)*, which is only one of many different things communicated in NOTAMs.

Answer (score 3):

In the United States, people who want to launch things into space need to apply for a license from the Federal Aviation Administration (FAA), in accordance with the Combined Federal Regulations (CFR) [Title 14](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14), Aeronautics and Space; [Chapter III](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-III), Commercial Space Transportation; [Subchapter C](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-III/subchapter-C), Licensing.  Before 2014, the FAA was less integrated in the process, so range closures tended to last longer.  US military launches follow different application procedures, and other countries have their own rules, but in the end all of these approaches produce the same thing: an area on a map which aircraft are prohibited to enter for some range of times, like this.

[image: range closure map for SpaceX launch from Florida in 2013]

That image was created by the US Air Force, but I've copied it from an [article in Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com/how-the-faa-reduces-flight-disruptions-during-rocket-launches-artemis-2022-8) magazine, with pictures of the current FAA control room and interviews with the people who work there.  The Notice to Air Missions (NOTAM) mentioned in Bojan Kogoj's comment is one of several kinds of messages that the FAA sends out over the week prior to  each planned launch.  The article quotes FAA space operations manager Duane Freer as saying

> "The aviation community knows there is an operation planned on a
> specific day, but it doesn't have specifics," Freer explained. "It
> gives them awareness, but then we give them specifics later, so it is
> an iterative approach informing them."  The agency also has a hotline
> open during missions, which has the range, operators, the Department
> of Defense, and all air traffic facilities involved, so they have
> real-team awareness of when the airspace should be closed and
> reopened.  "Even in the event of an anomaly, we know how long the
> debris will be present and the danger to aircraft," Freer explained.
> "So, if something were to go wrong, we could evacuate that airspace,
> which is an extra layer of safety."

An example they give of the kind of disruption to air traffic that a space launch causes is

> a SpaceX launch in 2018 impacted a total of 563 flights, collected
> 4,645 minutes of delays, and caused aircraft to fly an additional
> 34,841 miles to circumvent the restricted airspace